# return pointer within a GCD block

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Here is my case:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
         //Do long-running tasks
        if(/*some condition*/){
             //Continue long-running tasks
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             //UIKit stuff
            });
        return NO;
        }else{
             //Continue long-running tasks

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             //UIKit stuff
            });
         return YES;
}
});
}
```

Since the block is void return type, I got this compiler error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types passing 'BOOL(^)(void)' to parameter of type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void(^)(void)')
```

How to solve that?

Comment: queue.h: `typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);`

Comment: the long-running tasks should no be ran on the main thread and the `–textFieldShouldReturn:` is called on the main thread; your long-running tasks will just block the main thread.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, can the decision on `YES`/`NO` not be made until some long running task has been run for a while?

Answer (score 1):

Put your condition on the main thread and only do your long lasting task on the worker thread. Otherwise it makes no sense to dispatch on a worker thread since you have to return immediately from `textFieldShouldReturn` which means you either block the main thread or do as I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible what you wish to accomplish. At least not in this form.

Maybe you can tell us more about what you try to accomplish and we can provide an alternate solution.

I am curious why would you want a long duration task executed in `textFieldShouldReturn:` which is supposed to return a value immediately. It doesn't matter that you execute it asynchronously, the text field needs a value at that moment.

**EDIT**

Ok, I understand you must make a long duration search in coredata. Unfortunately `textFieldShouldReturn:` needs a return value.

`textFieldShouldReturn:` is just a delegate method that allows you to implement custom behaviour when pressing the Return key. Most commonly, the developer hides the keyboard.

My guess is that you are making a search in coredata before you can decide whether to hide the keyboard. In this case, I would

So, in `textFieldShouldReturn:` I suggest you hide the keyboard and somehow lock that keyboard to prevent editing. From that method you also trigger the coredata search async. When you get a response, you can decide whether to start editing that text field again (show the keyboard) or just move on.

How does it sound? Does it match your desired behavior?

Comment: Doing a search for a string in a big coredata entity take a long time and freeze the UI. That's why I preferred to get it done in background. Do you have better way ? Thanx.